# Qscintilla Авто отступ после знака :

Tags: python, pyqt5

Я пишу редактор кода на pyqt5+qscintilla. Но не могу сделать отступ после знака ":", как в питоне

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста минимальный пример демонстрирующий вашу проблему.